# Received unexpected error: pq: role "sumka" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I was created postgres image in docker. Then i can connect to postgres in DBeaver.

I can't solve this error.

Postgres query string `postgresql://sumka:secret@0.0.0.0:5432/simple_bank?sslmode=disable`

```
package db

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestCreateAccount(t *testing.T) {
    arg := CreateAccountParams{
        Owner:    "sumka",
        Balance:  10,
        Currency: "USD",
    }

    account, err := testQueries.CreateAccount(context.Background(), arg)

    require.NoError(t, err)
    require.NotEmpty(t, account)

    require.Equal(t, arg.Owner, account.Owner)
    require.Equal(t, arg.Balance, account.Balance)
    require.Equal(t, arg.Currency, account.Currency)

    require.NotZero(t, account.ID)
    require.NotZero(t, account.CreatedAt)
}
```

```
Error Trace:    account_test.go:19
Error:          Received unexpected error:
                pq: role "sumka" does not exist
Test:           TestCreateAccount
```

[image]

Comment: include the query details in your question

Comment: @arunjos007 sorry i was edited

Comment: @arunjos007 its my project https://github.com/suumiizxc/simplebank

Comment: Looks like you're connecting to the address `0.0.0.0`; I wonder if you could be connecting to a different postgres instance https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419880/connecting-to-ip-0-0-0-0-succeeds-how-why